# The integers $x+k\frac{n}{gcd(a,n)}$ with $k=0,...,gcd(a,n)-1$ are the only solutions to the equation $ax=b\pmod n$

Tags: number-theory

Let $gcd(a,n)>1$ and consider the equation:
$\frac{a}{gcd(a,n)}x = \frac{b}{gcd(a,n)}    \pmod{ \frac{n}{gcd(a,n)}}$.
Here, x is the unique solution mod $\frac{n}{gcd(a,n)}$

Comment: Yes, what you have written is true. Now what?

Comment: Sorry, I was looking for justification of this.  By construction, a/gcd should have an inverse since the gcd of a/gcd and n/gcd is one.  But why does k determine the only solutions?